# Is it possible to catch an IndexOutofBounds as a boolean value?

Tags: java, list, boolean, indexoutofboundsexception

So I don't want to avoid an IndexOutofBounds error; however, I want to know how to know when one hits it without crashing the program.

```
    List<String> pool = new ArrayList<>();
    pool.add("a"); 
    boolean checked = (pool.get(1) == null); //I know this doensn't work
    System.out.println(checked); //I want false
```

So in this example it is obvious that nothing exists in index 1 of my List pool. Is it possible to get a boolean value for this? Or is it possible to check if the end of a list has been reached without doing i < list.size()? Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Why don't you want to check `list.size()`?

Answer (score 2):

It's called a try-catch block:

```
boolean hasValue;
try {
    hasValue = (pool.get(i) != null);
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    hasValue = false;
}
// hasValue == true if non-null value found at index i
```

However this is an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) called "[exceptions as flow control](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why)".

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. You can check [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and see that other than checking the size there is no way to "fetch if exists" or to find if "does index exist".

Trying to access the index and catching the exception is possible but not recommended because [catching exceptions is an expensive operation in java](http://java-performance.info/throwing-an-exception-in-java-is-very-slow/)